# How do I export a 12c schema dump?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have successfully imported an 11g dump into my local 12c installation like this:

```
-- CREATE DATA_DUMP_DIR and give priviledges to SYSTEM
CREATE DIRECTORY main_data_pump_dir as 'C:\ade\aime_v\oracle\admin\seeddata\dpdump';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY main_data_pump_dir TO SYSTEM;

impdp system/Oracle_1@pdborcl directory=main_data_pump_dir dumpfile=myshema.dmp nologfile=Y
```

Now I am trying to export like this:

```
expdp myschema dumpfile=main_data_pump_dir:myschema.dmp reuse_dumpfiles=y nologfile=Y
```

or maybe this:

```
expdp myschema@pdborcl dumpfile=main_data_pump_dir:myschema.dmp reuse_dumpfiles=y nologfile=Y
```

But I can't seem to get it working.
Do I need to grant write to myschema?

Comment: 1) "I can't seem to get it working" isn't a valid Oracle error... please post the actual error that is returned.  2)  The export should be something more like: expdp system/Oracle_1@pdborcl schemas=myschema directory=main_data_pump_dir dumpfile=myshema.dmp nologfile=Y

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

```
expdp System/Oracle_1@pdborcl schemas=myschema dumpfile=main_data_pump_dir:myschema.dmp nologfile=yes reuse_dumpfiles=yes
```